# pandas: Parametric statistic test for two proportions (with H0: p1=p2). How to use scipy.stats?

Tags: python, numpy

Based on my source data, I create a dataframe with aggregated counts per share that looks like:

```
Share   Count_cm    Total_cm    Count_pm    Total_pm
A       117           395         309         1176
B        38           395         158         1176
C         4           395          22         1176
D         4           395           9         1176
E         8           395          19         1176
F        44           395         175         1176
G        37           395         110         1176
H        35           395         111         1176
I        11           395          21         1176
J        39           395          92         1176
K        16           395          48         1176
L        31           395          72         1176
M        11           395          30         1176
```

In order to run proportion tests between current month and previous month, I calculate the z score using the following function:

```
import numpy as np
def z_prop(c1,c2,n1,n2):
    numerator = c1/n1 - c2/n2
    p = (c1+c2)/(n1+n2)
    q = 1 - p
    denominator = np.sqrt(p*q*(1/n1 + 1/n2))
    return numerator/denominator
```

So the z score would be

```
df['Z']=z_prop(df['Count'],df['Count_pm'],df['Total'],df['Total_pm'])
```

and pValue I get from `df['pvalue']=np.abs(1-2*st.norm.sf(df['z']))`

At the end I create the following addition with rounding:

```
    Share   Count_cm    Total_cm    Count_pm    Total_pm    Z   pvalue
1     A      117          395         309         1176     1.29  0.80
2     B       38          395         158         1176    -1.96  0.95
3     C        4          395          22         1176    -1.16  0.75
4     D        4          395           9         1176     0.47  0.36
5     E        8          395          19         1176     0.54  0.41
6     F       44          395         175         1176    -1.86  0.94
7     G       37          395         110         1176     0.01  0.01
8     H       35          395         111         1176    -0.34  0.27
9     I       11          395          21         1176     1.22  0.78
10    J       39          395          92         1176     1.28  0.80
11    K       16          395          48         1176    -0.03  0.02
12    L       31          395          72         1176     1.20  0.77
13    M       11          395          30         1176     0.25  0.20
```

Hope my solution can help someone, but I would really like to get p-Values per share directly from the source file using PANDAS' groupby function and a statistical package like scipy.stats instead of creating the aggregated dataframe and defining the z_prop function.

Does anyone know such solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you see these little formatting buttons??

Comment: Do you suggest a solution or formatting is more important?

Comment: Formatting is important to make a question attractive and get an answer!